# Nginx rewrite-target overwritting domain/suffix/index.php to domain/index.php

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-reverse-proxy

recently I have deployed an kubernetes cluster which is running wordpress instance and phpmyadmin. I'm using Nginx ingress controller to perform path based routing for both the services. However, request to `/` is happening without any hassle but when I request `domain.com/phpmyadmin/` I get a login page after which I have been redirected to `domain.com/index.php` instead of `domain.com/phpmyadmin/index.php`. Please suggest me possible turn around for this. Thank you guys for the support :)

My ingress.yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
  annotations: 
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/add-base-url : "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "/$2"
    # ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "^/phpmyadmin/"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: example.domain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: wordpress
              servicePort: 80
          - path: /phpmyadmin(/|$)(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: phpmyadmin
              servicePort: 80
```

Comment: This configuration works as designed. If you will check [Ingress rewrite docs](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/) it will redirect `rewrite.bar.com/something/` rewrites to `rewrite.bar.com/` which I guess `index.php` is default backend here. Also which ingress version are you using? `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/add-base-url` was removed in `v0.22`. What response you get when you `curl` it?

Comment: @PjoterS Thank you for replying. Yes, I do see it's by design but the problem I'm facing is also a usecase. Currently I'm using v0.35 and the response I'm getting is 302 found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say issue is not on [Nginx Ingress](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/) side.

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "/$2"
...
- path: /phpmyadmin(/|$)(.*)
```

Should work properly for you.

However there is second part, configuration of `myphpadmin`. As you didn't provide this configuration I would guess what could cause this issue.

Like mentioned in [phpmyadmin docs](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#config), sometimes you need to set `$cfg['PmaAbsoluteUri']`

> In some setups (like separate SSL proxy or load balancer) you might have to set $cfg['PmaAbsoluteUri'] for correct redirection.

As I based on [this configuration](https://gist.github.com/dnaroma/178b3b187aa329c01b27d90a7b38709c), many depends on how you configured `PMA_ABSOLUTE_URI`, is it `http://somedomain.com/phpmyadmin` or different?
Is important as you might encounter situation like:

- When you enter to `http://somedomain.com/phpmyadmin` and login you will be redirected to `http://somedomain.com/` so `Ingress` will redirect you to `path: /` set in ingress
- If you will again enter `http://somedomain.com/phpmyadmin` you will be able to see `phpmyadmin` content, like you would be already logged in.

You could try to add `env` in your `myphpadmin` deployment. It would look similar like below:

```
  env:
    - name: PMA_ABSOLUTE_URI
      value: http://somedomain.com/myphpadmin/
```

Last thing, its not recommended to use expose `phpmyadmin` without `https`.

For some extra information you can read [this](https://blog.dnaroma.eu/2020/07/31/study-k8s-with-microk8s/) article.

**In short:**

- Nginx ingress configuration looks ok
- Check your `myphpadmin` configuration, especially `PMA_ABSOLUTE_URI`.

Comment: Thanks for guiding me to the issue. It turned out that my phpmyadmin docker image did not have PMA_ABSOLUTE_URI env as I was using bitnami/phpmyadmin I switched to phpmyadmin:5.0.1 and it worked. Thanks alot!! :)